# iPhone UINavigationController inside UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, xib

Steps:

- List item
- Create a project called Nav.
- Create a new `UIViewController` BaseViewController (with XIB) and FirstViewController (with XIB).
- In the `NavAppDelegat.h` define baseController variable

  ```
  @interface NavAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  BaseViewController *baseController;
  }
  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet BaseViewController *baseController;
  ```
- In the `NavAppDelegat.m` add baseController to the window:

  ```
  @synthesize baseController;
  (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
  [self.window addSubview:baseController.view];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
  }
  ```
- Open the BaseViewController.xib file and add `UINavigationController`, set its Root View Controller class and XIB to FirstViewController (in the inspector).
- Also connect navigationController variable with the `UINavigationController`.

I believe this should show me the FirstViewController with the navigation bar. If I do this directly on the MainWindow.xib things are working as I expected but here I can't see the navigation bar. What am I missing? THx!

UPDATE:
So the problem is only that in case I use `UINavigationController` inside some additional controller (BaseViewController.xib here) instead of MainWindow.xib i don't see the navigation bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell if you're trying to connect your navigation controller directly to your window, just from a second XIB (which should work) or if you're making your navigation controller a subview of another view, which won't work.

`UINavigationController` is only intended to be used as either the primary subview of a `UIWindow` or as a subview of a `UITabController`.  Apple doesn't want you embedding a navigation controller in other contexts.

See [Combined View Controller Interfaces](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html) in the View Controller Programming Guide for more details.

Comment: Hi Seamus, does that mean in my DetailedViewController of my UISplitViewController that I cannot have a UINavigationController with a UIViewController that interfaces a UITableView because I cannot hook up the navigationController sub view?

I can show the UINavigationController in my detailed view, but the tableview itself doesn't seem to render.

Comment: Combined View Controller Interfaces is now found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html